# Duplicating theme on wordpress multi site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried to duplicate existing theme but couldn't find it on dashboards.

I copied and paste that existing theme folder and renamed and changed in style.css

But I couldn't find that theme on wp dashboard.

So I installed Duplicate Theme plugin but it is also not working. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no network admin role, then you could enable that theme.
To enable that duplicated theme, you need to login as network Administrator, and go to appearance/ theme, there you could find checkbox with enable / disable.

You need to check so that sub-sites admin could find that theme on their sub sites.